# rails migration production db not working well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got problems while migrating my database in production mode.

migrationfile looks like this:

```
class ChangeCourseDefaultsNull < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
   change_column :course_objects, :active, false, :default => 0
 end

 def self.down
   change_column_null :course_objects, :active, true
 end
end
```

error is

```
== 20150720105700 ChangeCourseDefaultsNull: migrating  =========================
-- change_column(:course_objects, :active, false, {:default=>0})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `to_sym'
```

whats going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not specified the column type `boolean` or `string`, etc

```
class ChangeCourseDefaultsNull < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
  change_column :course_objects, :active, :boolean, :default => 0
 end

 def self.down
  change_column_null :course_objects, :active, :boolean
 end
end
```